# Bootstrap popover with link and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap popover to pop a confirmation window before deleting a record from my database-driven table.
The code used to generate column with delete buttons looks like this:

```
echo "<td> <div class=\"popover-example list-inline\"><a class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-toggle=\"popover\" title=\"Are you sure?\" data-content=\"<a href=\"delete.php?id='. $row->id.' \">Delete</a></div></td>";
```

and my popover js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popover-example a").popover({
        placement : 'top'
        html: 'true'
    });
});
```

I know, that this echo is bit messy, but it works with plain text.
I'd like to make the HTML with dynamically generated link appear in poprover. Is there any way to do it?
I'd be grateful for a tip.

Comment: What kind of tip do you want @hops? I don't see a question in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dynamic and custom content in a popover like so

```
var myDynamicContent = $('<a>').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com')
    .text('click here!');

$(".popover-example a").popover({
    placement : 'top'
    html: 'true'
    content: myDynamicContent
});
```

The `content` key of the `popover` plugin allows you to add custom content when the popover is triggered to open. You can also embed that value in the HTML markup, as a `data-content=""` value.